# программа не выводит дальше информацию через функцию пройдя один цикл

Tags: c

Не знаю в чем проблема. После выполнения одной функцию, ничего не выводится в консоль. Скорее всего это связано как то с циклом while, но пока точно не уверен

```
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    FILE* cfPtr;
    char fname[20]; 
    int choice;

    printf("Введите название файла (name.txt)\n-> ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", fname);

    if ((cfPtr = fopen(fname, "r+")) == NULL)
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
    else {
        while (true)
        {
            choice = ENTER_CHOICE();

            switch (choice)
            {
            case 0: return false;
            case 1:
                NEW_DATA(cfPtr);
                break;
            case 2:
                VIEW_DATA(cfPtr);
                break;
            case 3:
                UPDATE_RECORD(cfPtr);
                break;
            case 4:
                ADD_RECORD(cfPtr);
                break;
            case 5:
                DELETE_RECORD(cfPtr);
                break;
            case 6:
                SEARCH_RECORD(cfPtr);
                break;
            case 7:
                SORT_DATA(cfPtr);
                break;
            }
            fclose(cfPtr);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Кажется вы рано файл закрываете, надо в case 0 файл закрыть перед return, а так он внутри цикла после первой же итерации закрывается.

Comment: @CrazyElf нет к сожалению дело не в этом...

Comment: Из приведенного кода только та проблема, о которой сказал @CrazyElf, показывайте другой код, если хотите лучшего ответа.